# My method doesn't end

Tags: c#

I have a method for my menu, but it doesn't end...

```
static public int Menu(string M_1, string M_2, string M_3, string M_4) {
    int menu = 0;
    Write("1. " + M_1, 10, false);
    Write("2. " + M_2, 11, false);

    if (M_3 != "") {
        Write("3. " + M_3, 12, false);
    }

    if (M_4 != "") {
        Write("4. " + M_4, 13, false);
    }

    Console.Write("\n\nWrite a numbere of an Action and press ENTER:  ");

    while (true) {
        menu = Console.Read();

        if (menu != 1 || menu != 2 || menu != 3 || menu != 4) {
            continue;
        } else {
            break;
        }

    }
    return menu;
}
```

**Main Method:**
...

```
int menu1 = Menu("First", "Secong", "Third", "");

switch (menu1) {
    case 1:
        Console.Clear();
        Vypsat("You choose action 1.", 35);
        Console.ReadKey();
        break;

...
```

If I run program and press a number and Enter, everything stays the same. :( Whats the problem there?

Comment: I believe `Console.Read()` will always give you a string, which can never be equal to the integers you are testing against.

Comment: `if (menu != 1 || menu != 2 || menu != 3 || menu != 4)` - for what value of `menu` would you expect this overall expression to be false? If the value is 1 then it's not equal to 2, and if it's 2 then it's not equal to 1, etc.

Comment: change post title meaningful

Comment: @jbabey: You are on the right track, but the method returns the character code of one character at a time, not a string.

Comment: **You have an infinite loop which never returns false.**

Answer (score 5):

The `Console.Read` method returns the character code of the first character, it's doesn't parse what you type into a number.

If you type in `1` and press enter, the `Console.Read` will return the character code `49`, not the number `1`.

Also, this condition:

```
if (menu != 1 || menu != 2 || menu != 3 || menu != 4) {
```

will always be true. A value can only be equal to one number at a time, so there is no value that can be equal to all four numbers at the same time and make the condition false.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
if (menu != 1 || menu != 2 || menu != 3 || menu != 4)
```

Always returns true. Perhaps you meant:

```
if (menu != 1 && ...)
```

Answer (score 0):

`if (menu != 1 || menu != 2 || menu != 3 || menu != 4)`
 will always be true, because menu can only have one value at a time. I believe you want to replace || with &&.